# is there a way to commit only once per day?

Tags: onedrive

I'm fairly new to onedrive, so my question is probably really simple.

**Context :**

I'd like to be able to use some file without them committing to onedrive every time I save. However, I'd like this specific folder to be committed automatically, but only like 2 times a day or something like that. The time I don't care (and if I'm offline when it tries, as soon as I'm online again I'd like it to commit).

The reason is simple, on Microsoft Word, I save every 30 seconds and my connection is not that good. So i'd like this folder to be like offline and free for me to use without internet during the rest of the time.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this task with a third-party client just not without the default client.  Stick to a third-party application that supports syncing folders as a task, and which support doing so to OneDrive, that accomplishes what you want for the most part.

Comment: I see, onedrive doesn't support those tasks then... switch to google drive, would it be a better option?

Comment: I said the stock client doesn't support it not that the service doesn't support it.  Google Drive and Dropbox also don't support this type of workflow.  All of those types of clients are designed to upload the file when it changes.